# Show that the set $B := \left \{ (r,\infty) \mid r \in \mathbb{R}\right \} $ is a basis of some topology on $\mathbb{R}$, but not a topology itself.

Tags: general-topology

Show $B := \left \{ (r,\infty) \mid r \in \mathbb{R}\right \} $ is a basis of some topology on $\mathbb{R}$, but not a topology itself.

The definition of a topology basis is the following: A topological basis is a subset B of a set T in which all other open sets can be written as unions or finite intersections of B.

---

So to check if our $B$ is a basis, we have to check if the open sets of T can be written as unions or finite intersections of B? Can anyone explain how we can go about doing that?

Comment: Not unions **or** finite intersections, unions **of** finite intersections.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: this is a particularly simple case, because you can characterise exactly what the finite intersections of members of $B$ are, and then what their unions are.  The topology is the set of unions of finite intersections of members of $B$.
And there are exactly two sets in the topology that are not in $B$.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check that the sets cover $\mathbb{R}$ and the intersection of any two subsets can be written as a union of some of them.

$$\mathbb{R} = \cup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} ( -n, \infty) $$

$$(r_1, \infty) \cap (r_2, \infty) = (\max(r_1, r_2), \infty)$$

so yes, a basis ( in fact, the intersection of any two is one of the two).

However, not a topology since $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{R}$ not of form $(r, \infty)$.

The topology generated by these sets consists of $\emptyset$, $\mathbb{R}$ and all of the $(r, \infty)$.